# 12.04 freezes on install

Tags: 12.04, installation, hp-pavilion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What should I do when Ubuntu freezes?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4408/what-should-i-do-when-ubuntu-freezes)

I'm new to ubuntu and can't for the life of me understand how to get around this issue. I'm having a problem where when I insert the boot disk that i burned for 12.04, it loads and gives me the language option and select an installation type, i select either try ubuntu / install ubuntu and it begins to load. Then after about 5 mintues of the purple screen with the dots under the UBUNTU it freezes the whole computer, and the only way to get out is to turn off the laptop with the power button.

I have read previous threads saying people had similar "freezing" issues including ones that mention my model of laptop, HP Pavillion DV1000. But it appears their problems are post installation and relate to their wireless cards.

I have tried changing the boot options (F6) and I am totally stuck. Can anyone shed any light on to this issue?

Thanks in advance.........

Comment: Did you check the downloaded ISO file with md5sum?

Comment: As Mitch says, you should [`MD5SUM the .iso`](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HowToMD5SUM). You should also [verify the install CD/DVD or USB flash drive](http://zootlinux.blogspot.com/2010/05/check-disc-for-defects-in-ubuntu-1004.html). Also, what boot options did you try? Please **edit your answer** to include all this information.

Comment: I doubt it has anything to do with the iso being ok, sometimes ubuntu does freeze on certain hardware. No clear solution is known for that.